# Regexp for URL cache in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to match a certain Regexp pattern in Java and I think I'm very close, could anyone with more experience help? I have been testing it for at least a few hours and couldn't come to a solution yet.

This Regexp is mounted based on a URL, and must represent a "key" to this URL, since depending on the source it may change a lot, but a few stuff is always there... Already mapped Strings to match:

http://fictionalURL:8080/servlet/TPCW_new_products_servlet;jsessionid=865266C8B1231C35FEDEAA9D66400074?subject=POLITICS

http://fictionalURL.:8080/servlet/TPCW_buy_request_servlet;jsessionid=6FA80FDC52BB22518DB7D587E0876D63?RETURNING_FLAG=Y&UNAME=OGREREBABAREAT&PASSWD=ogrerebabareat&C_ID=1440046&SHOPPING_ID=171

http://localhost:8080/servlet/;jsessionid=865266C8B1231C35FEDEAA9D66400074?subject=POLITICS

my code is built so that the part that represents the URL pattern is built on runtime:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test_regexp {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        String testString = "http://ec2-54-158-62-71.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/servlet/TPCW_buy_request_servlet;jsessionid=6FA80FDC52BB22518DB7D587E0876D63?RETURNING_FLAG=Y&UNAME=OGREREBABAREAT&PASSWD=ogrerebabareat&C_ID=1440046&SHOPPING_ID=171";
        int beginIndex = testString.indexOf("servlet");
        int endIndex = testString.indexOf("jsessionid");
        CharSequence cs = new String(testString);
        String patt = "\\(?=.*:8080/.*)(?=.*jsessionid=).*";
        System.out.println("Pattern: "+patt);
        Pattern teste = Pattern.compile(patt);

        System.out.println(teste.matcher(cs).matches());
    }
}
```

but at the end the pattern should look *something* like this:

Pattern: ((?=.*:8080/.*)(?=.*jsessionid=).*)

PS: The pattern must include the URL full endpoint (with parameters), but not the sessionId and other stuff

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the regexp must also have the subject parameter, which is after the session ID, I have only realized it while writing this...

For those who want to know what's my purpose on all that, I'm making a LRU cache based on Regexp Patterns stored in a HashSet.

I would apprecite the help very much! This is the last task to finish the project!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your pattern. I'm not sure what the backslash out front is for.

```
"\\(?=.*:8080/.*)(?=.*jsessionid=).*"
```

Your pattern would also happily match `jsessionid=10:8080/`